# Best way to convert this firebase real time database structure to firestore data structure?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to convert [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSCkf.png) firebase real time database structure to firestore data structure please do some help.

I want that structure like Posts(collection)/pin(collection)/pid(document)/then the post description , but i know that a collection can't contain another collection so how should i do?

All_Posts node contain pid and pin only to share that post and then get the post details using the pin and pid.

One more thing in my structure Posts-->734...(pin)-->pid-->then post details because i want to retrieve all the pids and the details under a pin .So should i do in this way or like Posts-->pids(which contain pin number)--> then fetch the details. Which one i should do?

Comment: Usually you structure a Firestore database according to the quries that you want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo Queries like ** show all the posts under a pin. , Users Personal Details in their profile etc.**

Answer (score 1):

### Cloud Firestore Data model

> **Cloud Firestore is a NoSQL, document-oriented database. Unlike a SQL database, there are no tables or rows. Instead, you store data in documents, which are organized into collections.**
>
> > Each document contains a set of key-value pairs. Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.
> >
> > All documents must be stored in collections. Documents can contain subcollections and nested objects, both of which can include primitive fields like strings or complex objects like lists.
> >
> > Collections and documents are created implicitly in Cloud Firestore. Simply assign data to a document within a collection. If either the collection or document does not exist, Cloud Firestore creates it.

Access the link to have more information about **[Cloud Firestore Data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)**

---

### Your DB structure

> In regards to your case scenario, you **can** have **collections within other collections** , these are called **subcollections**, as the example for a chat app shows here:

[image]

> **You can access these subcollections with the same collection ID by using [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).**

---

### Moving Data from Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore

For the sake of keeping this answer brief, check this link if you are planning on **[Moving data from Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb)** to consult best practices and recommendations.

Comment: Is my data structure design is right in terms of real time data?

Comment: As far as I understand from your explanation. You would need to create a Collection ~> documents ~> subcollection. Remember that a subcollection is always tied to a document. For example:

Posts (Collection) ~> postID (Document) ~> add any collection you need for that specific post (Collection)

Notice that you cannot have (Collection-Collection-Document) like this: 
Posts (Collection) ~>  add any collection you need for that specific post (Collection) ~> postID (Document)

Comment: understood ... i will try